# Attribute a different value to a variable depending on the class from which you are coming (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

In my `HomeClass` there is a `static var globalLimit: Int = 0` and i have to pass his value in other classes, this is my prepare function

```
 override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {



           if let vc = segue.destination as? SelectClass {
                  vc.limit = Int(steppeR.value)
                  HomeClass.globalLimit = Int(steppeR.value)
                  HomeClass.globalRadiusLimit = Int(stepperRadius.value) 
        }
           else if let np = segue.destination as? CourseClass2 {
            np.categories = filteredList
            np.numberPlaces = filteredList.count
            np.radius = Int(stepperRadius.value)
        }

    }
```

now the problem is this, in my `CourseClass2` class that i can even reach from  `SelectClass` i have the `var numberPlaces = 0` and his value is

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        numberPlaces = HomeClass.globalLimit

    }
```

but like you can see in my prepare function when i come in `CourseClass2` directly from `HomeClass` i want that the value of `numberPlaces = filteredList.count` but of course it does not work because it goes against it `numberPlaces = HomeClass.globalLimit` in the viewDidload of `CourseClass2`, so how can i solve this problem?

Comment: Just declare var numberPlaces =  HomeClass.globalLimit as stored property and remove its initialization from viewDidLoad

Comment: how can i do this?

Comment: where you have declared numberPlaces, in CourseClass2, just give it the value. This would be its default value which can be changed later, that is what you will be going to do in HomeClass

Comment: i tried but  it not work

Comment: Don't set `numberOfPlaces` is your `viewDidLoad`.  Make the setting of that value the responsibility of the calling `viewController`.

Comment: I tried but it still do not work

Answer (score 0):

Try in this way:

**Set your numberPlaces var as optional:**

```
var numberPlaces: Int?
```

**Then check in view did load if it is nil:**

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    if numberPlaces == nil {
        numberPlaces = HomeClass.globalLimit
    }
}
```